# Moving contribution page to a new campaign - consequences?

Tags: contribution-page, civicampaign

quick question: Having a contribution page under campaign A.. We're creating a new campaign ("B") now but wish to use the same old contribution page.

How are the past records (donations+pcps) affected?

Comment: If no one gives  a definite answer this is something you could easily answer yourself with a few minutes on the demo site. Just create a Campaign and Contrib. page. Add a couple of payments via the page. then create a new Campaign, change the page. add new payments. check the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The contributions hold the campaign at the time they were made so not affected. PCPs created also keep the old campaign against them (using my memory here!). Any new PCPs or contributions will use the current campaign against the contribution page that initiated them.

Comment: Yes! thank you. Turns out the contributions continue to be tied to the old campaign. So those transactions may need to be updated as well.